# How can I fix a "GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent" warning if my Dialog is the topmost window?

Tags: gtk, gtk3

I have a program that simply creates a GtkDialog and then calls gtk_widget_show_all on it. The GTKDialog acts as the "main window" of the program, in practice.

Everything seems to be working alright but I get a warning from GTK saying ""GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.". How can I fix this? Do I need to create an invisible window to be the parent for my dialog?

Answer (score 2):

Well the question would be why you used GtkDialog instead of GtkWindow. The warning is harmless but that is a weird design choice to make a dialog the main window.

Comment: This program is part of a demo for a library so I think its just showing off how to create dialogs in the simplest way possible. Anyway, suppose I want to write a program that only needs to ask the user for some input with a dialog. I don't want to have any other visible windows other than the dialog. Should I still structure my program so the dialog is the main window or is there some other way?

Comment: In that case, you should use a GtkWindow instead of a GtkDialog. You can build your UI pretty much in the same way — after all, a GtkDialog is a GtkWindow with a box where to put the content and a button box for the controls. The issue is that GtkDialog hints to the windowing system that it's connected to another window; without, you're breaking the semantics of the class.